# Isometric tile map flickers for GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT24_OES

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I've used `GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT24_OES` to control the depth for updating the `vertexZ` of my character as it moves on the tile map.

Problem is, as the character moves, there are some flickers appearing on iPhone iPad devices.  Flicker **does not** appear in simulator.

How to resolve this ? Any suggestions?

Comment: did you set the framebuffer mode to RGBA8888 (default is RGB565)?

Comment: how to set framebuffer mode in cocos2d sir ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use

`kEAGLColorFormatRGBA8`

instead of

`kEAGLColorFormatRGB565`

in your

> AppDelegate

all thanks to [LearnCocos2D](https://stackoverflow.com/users/201863/learncocos2d)